# Error on domReady callback: TypeError: b is null arcgis

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm getting this error "Error on domReady callback: TypeError: b is null" when including arcgis javascript api to my project.

```
     <head runat="server">
<title></title>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     var dojoConfig = {
         async: true,
         parseOnLoad: true,
     };
</script>
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/"></script>
</head>
 <body>
<div id="layerContent" style="height:10%;width:100%;">
    <div id="map" style="height:10%;width:100%;">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This script is in page called map.aspx and I request it using iframe like this

```
   <iframe src="map.aspx" />
```

I'm not sure what is the problem, any help?

Comment: is the code wrapped in the HTML tag? Also i noticed the comma after parseOnLoad which can cause issues in IE

Comment: It is wrapped in HTML, the problem became when I added another javascript libraries, like bootstrap and others.

Comment: Move all JS libraries below the Esri JS